# setPreferredSize Java

Tags: java

Извините за глупый вопрос, но обязательно ли в качестве аргумента setPreferredSize использовать объект Dimension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это можно легко проверить, заглянув в [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html).

> setPreferredSize(Dimension preferredSize)
>   Sets the preferred size of this component.

Других методов там нет, следовательно, метод больше никак не переопределен.

Answer (score 1):

Обязательно. Вы задаете размеры, передавая в функцию объект с требуемыми параметрами.